# show location of pointer when I press the _____ key

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, mouse-cursor

In mouse options there is an option:

> show location of pointer when i press the ctrl key

Can I trigger it with a different key instead? I want the "mouse sonar" feature enabled, but I use ctrl+click for work all the time. Is it possible to use a different key to locate the mouse?

[image]